# How can i handle the rotation issue with Preview & FaceDetection

Tags: android, canvas, camera, rotation, preview

i got some issue nagging me for quite some time now.

I got my custom Camera-App that shows a live Preview. Aswell i am using the FaceDetection for getting a better focus on peoples faces. When i check my taken Pictures in Gallery i can see the Rectangle correctly. The next step is to make the FaceDetection-Rectangle visible in the Live-Preview. So i decided to use a canvas that gets the coordinates from the Preview-Rectangle and transform them to coordinates that can be used by the canvas.

My problem is that i had to rotate the Preview by 90degrees that it shows the Preview correctly. So when i also rotate the View of the canvas before i draw it, the rectangle shows correctly and moves the right axis aswell. BUT the rectangle can move out of screen on left and right, and only uses about half of the available height. I assume that the rotating causes the trouble, but i can't manage to put things right. Someone got an idea?

Screenshot (i added purple lines to show the top/bottom-parts that cant be reached by red rectangle):
[image]

**Preview:**

```
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mCamera.getParameters();
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);          
        mCamera.setFaceDetectionListener(new FaceDetectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFaceDetection(Face[] faces, Camera camera) {

                        if(mDraw != null) {
                            mDraw.update(f.rect, f);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        mCamera.startFaceDetection();
}

private DrawOnTop  mDraw = null;
public void setDrawOnTop(DrawOnTop d) {
    this.mDraw = d;
}
```

**DrawOnTop:**

```
public DrawOnTop(Context context) {
    super(context);
    myColor = new Paint();

    myColor.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    myColor.setColor(Color.RED);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        rect.set((((rect.left+1000)*1000) / WIDTH_DIVISOR),(((rect.top+1000)*1000) / HEIGHT_DIVISOR),(((rect.right+1000)*1000) / WIDTH_DIVISOR),(((rect.bottom+1000)*1000) / HEIGHT_DIVISOR ));         
        setRotation(90);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, myColor);
}

public void update(Rect rect, Face face) {
    this.invalidate();
    this.rect = rect;
    this.face = face;
}
```

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

**EDIT:**
i came to the conclusion that this is a rare but known bug and that there is so far no other solution but forcing the application to landscape-mode. Works ok, but dimensions look a bit stretched or clinched  depending on which perspective the user is operating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I misread the question and talked about the wrong rectangle. This is what i meant:

Basically, you just need to scale the purple rectangle. Find ut where it is defined, then put it onto a canvas and do the following:

```
float screenWidth = /*get the width of your screen here*/;
float xScale = rect.width / screenWidth;

float screenHeight = /*get the height of your screen here*/;
float yScale = rect.height / screenWidth;

canvas.setScaleX(xScale);
canvas.setScaleY(yScale);
```

This way, the coordinates will be translated properly.

SECOND EDIT (in response to your comment): You can also do this with views, if you like.
Have fun.

Comment: it shows no more rectangle then. My colleague thinks that i will have to use translate in this case!?

Comment: @bofredo - i fail to see what translate could do for you here. But i see that i may have misread your question. Is `rect`the red rectangle or the purple one? If it is the red one, where do you specify th purple rectangle?

Comment: rect is the red one.  i drew the purple lines with gPaint only to show the bounds that red-rect can't exceed.

Comment: @bofredo - thats a bummer. you need to find the purple rectangle in your algorithm, then scale it as i suggested. ill edit my answer.

Comment: found this short todo:  "So we have to convert from (-1000, -1000)~(1000, 1000) to (0, 0)~(width, height of the View) in onDraw() of DrawingView."

Comment: i did alot of testing and came to the conclusion that i somehow have to get on a higher level and try to modify the View itself.