# Android camera2.params.face rectangle placement on canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, camera, face-detection

I'm trying to implement face detection in my camera preview. I followed the Android reference pages to implement a custom camera preview in a `TextureView`, placed in a `FrameLayout`. Also in this `FrameLayout` is a `SurfaceView` with a clear background (overlapping the camera preview). My app draws the `Rect` that is recognized by the first `CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACES` face's bounds  dynamically to the `SurfaceView`'s canvas, every time the camera preview is updated (once per frame). My app assumes only one face will need to be recognized.

My issue arises when I draw the rectangle. I get the rectangle in the correct place if I keep my face in the center of the camera view, but when I move my head upward the rectangle moves to the right, and when I move my head to the right, the rectangle moves down. It's as if the canvas needs to be rotated by -90, but this doesn't work for me (Explained below code).

in my activity's `onCreate()`:

```
//face recognition
rectangleView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.rectangleView);
rectangleView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
rectangleView.getHolder().setFormat(
    PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT); //remove black background from view
purplePaint = new Paint();
purplePaint.setColor(Color.rgb(175,0,255));
purplePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

in `TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener.onSurfaceTextureAvailable()`(in the `try{}` block that encapsulates `camera.open()` :

```
Rect cameraBounds = cameraCharacteristics.get(
    CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);
cameraWidth = cameraBounds.right;
cameraHeight = cameraBounds.bottom;
```

in the same listener within `onSurfaceTextureUpdated()` :

```
if (detectedFace != null && rectangleFace.height() > 0) {
        Canvas currentCanvas = rectangleView.getHolder().lockCanvas();
        if (currentCanvas != null) {
            currentCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            int canvasWidth = currentCanvas.getWidth();
            int canvasHeight = currentCanvas.getHeight();
            int l = rectangleFace.right;
            int t = rectangleFace.bottom;
            int r = rectangleFace.left;
            int b = rectangleFace.top;
            int left = (canvasWidth*l)/cameraWidth;
            int top  = (canvasHeight*t)/cameraHeight;
            int right = (canvasWidth*r)/cameraWidth;
            int bottom = (canvasHeight*b)/cameraHeight;

            currentCanvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, purplePaint);
        }
        rectangleView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(currentCanvas);
    }
```

method `onCaptureCompleted` in `CameraCaptureSession.CameraCallback` called by `CameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest()` looper:

```
//May need better face recognition sdk or api
Face[] faces = result.get(CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACES);

if (faces.length > 0)
{
    detectedFace = faces[0];
    rectangleFace = detectedFace.getBounds();
}
```

All variables are instantiated outside of the functions.

***In case you can't quite understand my question or need additional information, a similar question is posted here:***

[How can i handle the rotation issue with Preview & FaceDetection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875260/how-can-i-handle-the-rotation-issue-with-preview-facedetection)

However, unlike the above poster, I couldn't even get my canvas to show the rectangle after rotating my canvas, so that can't be the solution.

I tried to rotate my points by -90 degrees using x=-y, y=x (left=-top, top=left), and it doesn't do the trick either. I feel like some kind of function needs to be applied to the points but I don't know how to go about it.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Nine hello! i saw your question and as far as i understand you have done face detection (Camera 2 API). I am a rookie in Android, and trying make face detection during 3 weeks but without success... Would you please prompt me in which part of code you implement face detection... it will be very helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: @Aleksey, look above at "onCaptureCompleted" method

Comment: Is this camera2 API's STATISTICS_FACES an alternative to Firebase or ML Kit face detection? Does anyone know how they compare? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference, this is the solution I ended up with:

set a class/Activity variable called `orientation_offset` :

```
orientation_offset = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
```

This is the angle that the camera sensor's view (or rectangle for face detection) needs to be rotated to be viewed correctly.

Then, I changed `onSurfaceTextureUpdated()` :

```
Canvas currentCanvas = rectangleView.getHolder().lockCanvas();
    if (currentCanvas != null) {

        currentCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

        if (detectedFace != null && rectangleFace.height() > 0) {

            int canvasWidth = currentCanvas.getWidth();
            int canvasHeight = currentCanvas.getHeight();
            int faceWidthOffset = rectangleFace.width()/8;
            int faceHeightOffset = rectangleFace.height()/8;

            currentCanvas.save();
            currentCanvas.rotate(360 - orientation_offset, canvasWidth / 2, 
                canvasHeight / 2);

            int l = rectangleFace.right;
            int t = rectangleFace.bottom;
            int r = rectangleFace.left;
            int b = rectangleFace.top;
            int left = (canvasWidth - (canvasWidth*l)/cameraWidth)-(faceWidthOffset);
            int top  = (canvasHeight*t)/cameraHeight - (faceHeightOffset);
            int right = (canvasWidth - (canvasWidth*r)/cameraWidth) + (faceWidthOffset);
            int bottom = (canvasHeight*b)/cameraHeight + (faceHeightOffset);

            currentCanvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, purplePaint);
            currentCanvas.restore();
        }
    }
    rectangleView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(currentCanvas);
```

I'll leave the question open in case somebody else has a solution to offer.

Comment: Nice solution! It's still not very exact tho